# Create new row in a dataframe using the value from different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new in Python or coding per se. I need your help. So I have 2 dataframe here containing different columns for data learning process. The first data frame contains Intents and Responses with PID. The second data frame spntains Intent and Phrases. I want to use PID information in the first dataframe to create new column in second dataframe that contains team.

first dataframe (var 'finalchat')

```
intent              response                                 Pid
PizzaDelivery       What Pizza do you like?                  1.4.6
WeatherForecast     What do you want to know the weather?    2
Emergency Number    Dial 911                                 10.8.9
```

second dataframe (var 'intentdatas')

```
intent              response                                 
PizzaDelivery       I want to order a pizza                  
WeatherForecast     What's the weather in Manila             
Emergency Number    What's the number to dial?
```

I want to get the first value in of Pid in the first dataframe. Which are 1, 2, and 3 and compare it with hardcoded condition where if its both TRUE then it will create a column in second dataframe with is 'Team'.

Here's the code I'm trying out but when I run it. It doesn't show anything.

```
row_list = []
for index,row in intentdatas.iterrows():
    if ([re.search("1",index) is not None for index in 
    finalchat['Pid'].astype(str).str[0]] == 'TRUE'):
    row_list.append({'intent': row['intent'], 'phrases': row['phrases'], 
    'Team': 'Pizza'})
elif ([re.search("2",index) is not None for index in 
     finalchat['Pid'].astype(str).str[0]] == 'TRUE'):
     row_list.append({'intent': row['intent'], 'phrases': row['phrases'], 
     'Team': 'Weather'})
elif ([re.search("10",index) is not None for index in 
     finalchat['Pid'].astype(str).str[1]] == 'TRUE'):
    row_list.append({'intent': row['intent'], 'phrases': row['phrases'], 
    'Team': 'Emergency'})

intentdatas.head(10)
```

Expected out put

```
Intent              Response                          Team                   
PizzaDelivery       I want to order a pizza           Pizza     
WeatherForecast     What's the weather in Manila      Weather      
Emergency Number    What's the number to dial?        Emergency
```

Someone told that I can't compare a list to Singleton which is the TRUE statement. Maybe that's why there's nothing outputs whenever i print the intentdatas. Please help me. thanks!

Comment: "I want to get the first value in of Pid in the first dataframe. Which are 1, 2, and 3"...I think you mean "1, 2, and 10".

Comment: @andrew_reece yes andrew. sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge your data frames, then map teams from `Pid` values.

```
team_map = {"1":"Pizza", "2":"Weather", "10":"Emergency"}

df = intentdatas.merge(finalchat[["intent","Pid"]], on="intent")

df.assign(team=df.Pid.apply(lambda x: team_map[x.split(".")[0]])).drop("Pid", 1)

             intent                      response          team
0     PizzaDelivery       I want to order a pizza         Pizza
1   WeatherForecast  What's the weather in Manila       Weather
2  Emergency Number    What's the number to dial?     Emergency
```

Comment: I get an error in on="intent" code which is KeyError: 'intent'. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: You data show lowercase i for `intent` but your expected output shows capital I. That could be the reason.